# Emulate look of book using scrbook?

Tags: books, scrbook

I read somewhere about an option or a package to `scrbook` that allowed you to emulate/replicate the look of `book`, but now I can't seem to find it. Could you point me in the right direction? (Or did I dream this?)

Comment: Do you mean the `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles` option?

Comment: Or do you mean option `emulatestandardclasses`?

Comment: Why not just use the `book` class instead of trying to emulate it?

Comment: @PeterWilson I've never used `scrbook` before and so I'm trying it out. I like the idea of being able to set any font size, but I felt that the different styles went a bit too far and so I wanted to *ease* into KOMA Script :-)

Comment: If you only need the font size feature: use the `book` class and load package `scrextend` (part of the KOMA-Script bundle) with option `fontsize`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also the option `emulatestandardclasses`. Note that this option loads package `scrlayer-scrpage`. So it can not be used together with `fancyhdr`.

```latex
\documentclass[
  emulatestandardclasses
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[2-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The option `emulatestandardclasses` is not mentioned in the manual of KOMA.

Comment: Unfortunaly it is only mentioned in the German printed book.

Answer (score 7):

You emulate the look of `book` by using the document class option

```
headings=standardclasses
```

Example

```
\documentclass[
  headings=standardclasses,
]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{A section}

text

\end{document}
```

[image]

You get the look of `scrbook`, but with serif titles, with the option

```
egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles
```

Comment: What a badge of honor! I too do not particularly like serif titles. At least not the default ones :-)

Comment: For koma  v3.39 or newer there is now the class option `sfdefaults=false` instead of `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`